# Move file from Linux to windows server

Tags: talend, samba

I'm using Talend ETL tool.

What I'm trying to do is moving file from Linux machine to windows server and back to again to linux server after some work on that.

Is that possible we could achieve using Talend ?

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: You could use tFTP components for that if you setup ftp or tFileCopy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Talend job is running on Linux and the remote file server is Windows and the remote file server is not running an SFTP or FTP server.

To copy from a Windows system to local system, you can use the built in component [tFileFetch](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tFileFetch), which can copy files from a Samba share.

To copy files from Linux (Talend Job server) to the Windows file server, you'll likely need a third-party component. Look in the [Talend Exchange](https://exchange.talend.com/) site for the components "Samba copy", tSambaPut, tSambaFileCopy, tSambaGet, etc.

Alternatively, you could put an SFTP or FTP server on the Windows server. Then, it becomes very simple and you can just use the tFTP* series of components.